# Omitting 'N' sets of elements from array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, tcl

I have an array a[] with a set of elements(more than 100 elements), when an input 'N' and 'M' is given it has to neglect the 'N' number of elements in the array, 'M' should be 1 or 2 whether to neglect 1st or 2nd set of 'N' elements and proceed this till the end of the array.. and write this O/P to a new array b[].

For example, if

```
a[]= {10,20,30,40,60,70,80,90,100}

if N=2, M=1
    O/p should be b[] = {30,40,80,90}

if N=2, M=2
    O/p should be b[] = {10,20,60,70,100}
```

How can i do this in TCL or C?? TCL code will be highly appreciated and i have the array index set to '1' and not '0'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl lists are indexed from 0.

```
set a [list 10 20 30 40 60 70 80 90 100]
set N 2
foreach M {1 2} {
    set b [list]
    for {set i [expr {$M==1 ? $N : 0}]} {$i < [llength $a]} {incr i [expr {2*$N}]} {
        set b [concat $b [lrange $a $i [expr {$i+$N-1}]]]
    }
    puts "$M: $b"
}
```

outputs

```
1: 30 40 80 90
2: 10 20 60 70 100
```

Comment: glenn jackman im using array which has the index from '1'. I cannot use list because the code which is dependant on this part uses the array..Could you provide me the code with array ,whose index starts from '1' and not '0'

Comment: @user1270123, let me get this straight, you have `array set a {1 10 2 20 3 30 4 40 5 60 6 70 7 80 8 90 9 100}`, is that right?

Comment: Why would you use an array (map) like that instead of a list? It looks like you're working from the context of a C array ... which is analogous to a Tcl list.

Comment: yes, i need to change myself to TCL, Just new to tcl.. I'm kinda seeing everything from C point of view.. need to change and use the built in commands in TCL, but now I'm in the middle , so can't change the array to list, which results in changing my code from the scratch

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can do it like this:

```
char * getShorterArray(char * my_array, size_t size, int n, int m) {
    char * res_arr;
    res_arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size - n)); 
    //                               ^ calculate the size of the result array
    if (res_arr == NULL)
        return res_arr;
    if (m > 0)
        memcpy(res_arr, my_array, m); // copy elements before m
    if (size - (m+n) > 0)
        memcpy(&res_arr[m], &my_array[m+n], size - (m+n)); //copy elements at the end
    return res_arr; 
}
```

Note that I started from index 0, not 1. Also, the memory should be `free`ed once you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript version for comparison:

```
function neglect(arr, size, skip)
{
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (!(((i / size) ^ skip) & 1))
      result.push(arr[i]);
  return result;
}
```

My take at a C version (mutates the array in-place, returns the new length):

```
int neglect(int[] arr, int len, int size, int skip)
{
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (!(((i / size) ^ skip) & 1))
      arr[result++] = arr[i];
  return result;
}
```

Note that my algorithm is not designed with efficiency in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
int neglect(int n, int m, int *a, int alen) {
    int *b = a;
    int src = 0;
    int dst = 0;

    a = (m == 1 ? a + n : a)
    alen = (m == 1 ? alen - n : alen)
    while (src < alen) {
        if (m == 2 && src % (n * 2) < n)
            b[dst++] = a[src++];
        else
            src++;
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                     set N 3
                     set dic [array size dnlink]
                 set h 1    
    for { set i $N} {$i <= [expr $dic - 1] } {incr i [expr {2*$N}]} {

                    for {set j $i} {$j <= [expr {$i+$N-1}] } {incr j} {

                set k [expr {$i+$N-1}]
                                if { $k <= [expr $dic - 1] } {

                                         set dn($h) $dnlink($j) 
                     incr h 
                                      } 
                                                                                      }

                                                                                      }
```

Comment: Here, I'm able to get the 'N' sets of elements, But I'm loosing the  elements in  the last iteration where the number of elements are < N    if my array is {1,10,2,20,3,30,40,4,40,5,50,6,60,7,70,8,80,9,90} I'm losing the element 90 in my output array , how can i get these trailing elements

Comment: int N =3;
int dic = length(dnlink)
int h=1;

for(int i=N;i<= (dic-1); i+= (2*N)){


  for(set j=i;j<=(i+N-1);j++){
                             
         set k=(i+N-1)
         if(k <= (dic-1)){
                         
          dn[h]=dnlink[j];
          h++;
                         }

                             }

}